# XSSFSheet cannot be cast to java.io.File

Tags: java, database, apache-poi, inputstream

I am reading some values from a spesific sheet of excel workbook. I am adding these values to my database. There isnt any problem for this

But I also want to store the sheet of the workbook to my database BLOB cell.

I am trying to convert the sheet to Byte[]. I use below code.

I am trying to cast the sheet to java.io.File. But I am getting the below exception

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet cannot be cast to java.io.File

```
public  byte[] convertPDFToByteArray() {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    File file = (File) oku.wb.getSheet("İN");

    try {

        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Is there a way to cast the  ***"wb.getSheet("İN");"***  to java.io.File or any better way ?

Comment: No, there is no way to cast XSSFSheet to File. You can save whole xlsx document into a file using XSSFWorkbook.write() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just cast between two unrelated classes. 
In your case, I think you should use `getBytes()` of the sheet's workbook since the sheet object does not have this:

```
byte[] buffer = sheet.getWorkbook().getBytes();
```

It looks as though your `oku.wb` already contains the workbook, in that case you can call `getBytes()` directly on `oku.wb`:

```
byte[] buffer = oku.wb.getBytes();
```

**EDIT** Blast, I picked this code from one of my own projects, but that used `HSSFSheet` instead of `XSSFSheet`. So, your best best is to use the workbook's `write()` method as outlined in the comments:

```
public byte[] convert(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        sheet.getWorkbook().write(baos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // blah
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This code is working but a little problem.  This is storing the whole workbook. I want to store the only the sheet named "İN"

Comment: An `XSSFSheet` is _always_ contained in an `XSSFWorkbook` so you cannot save them separately. Your best best would be to experiment with the `wb.cloneSheet()` method to see if you can create a new workbook with just your sheet in it.